# Flutter: Canvas gives error on setState - painting random circles after a condition is satisfied

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, setstate

I'm trying to do the following in my code:

1. the user can click on the plus button and increment the counter.
2. if the counter is more than or equal to 4, the user can no longer press the plus button, since the absorb pointer, turns it's absorb field to true.
3. after the point where the button cannot be pressed, on each tap, the canvas changes the offset and the color of the circle and then, the build widget rebuilds the entire page (there is a GestureDetector widget as the parent of the AbsorbPointer widget to check taps on the entire screen and set new offset and color to the circle.)

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  bool absorbPointer = false;
  Color color = Colors.red;
  Offset offset = const Offset(0,0);

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  void _setRandomCircle(double maxHeight, double maxWidth) {
    var rnd = Random();
    double randWidth = rnd.nextInt(maxWidth.toInt() - 0).toDouble();
    double randHeight = rnd.nextInt(maxHeight.toInt() - 0).toDouble();
    offset = Offset(randWidth, randHeight);
  }

  void _setRandomColor() {
    color = Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
        .withOpacity(1.0);
  }

  void _setAbsorbPointer(){
    absorbPointer = true;
    setState(() {});
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double maxWidth = size.width;
    double maxHeight = size.height;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (_counter < 4) {
          _incrementCounter();
        } else {
          _setRandomColor();
          _setRandomCircle(maxHeight, maxWidth);
          _setAbsorbPointer();
        }
      },
      child: AbsorbPointer(
        absorbing: absorbPointer,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text(
                      'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$_counter',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              CustomPaint(
                painter: MyPainter(
                  offsetOfCircle: offset,
                  colorOfCircle: color,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My problem:
Nothing seems to work properly and I get these errors:
"UnimplementedError"
"Each child must be laid out exactly once."

with these details:
The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following child:
_ScaffoldSlot.body: RenderErrorBox#f9667 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); id=_ScaffoldSlot.body
constraints: MISSING
size: MISSING

---

And this is Mypainter:

```
class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color colorOfCircle;
  final Offset offsetOfCircle;

  MyPainter({required this.colorOfCircle, required this.offsetOfCircle});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var hexColor = "0x${colorOfCircle.value.toRadixString(16)}";
    var myCustomPaint = Paint()..color = Color(int.parse(hexColor));
    canvas.drawCircle(offsetOfCircle, 20, myCustomPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include `MyPainter` if it is needed to reproduce the issue

Comment: I edited my question. and thanks for putting time on this issue. I'm really stuck.

Comment: uh... you wonder why you get the exception *that you raise yourself* in code that clearly says "TODO: implement"?

Answer (score 0):

The code structure you are following, it is little different. You can do it the way you described, you dont need to use extra `AbsorbPointer` widget tap event.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  bool absorbPointer = false;
  Color color = Colors.red;
  Offset offset = const Offset(0, 0);

  void _setRandomCircleColorAndPosition(double maxHeight, double maxWidth) {
    double randWidth = math.Random().nextDouble() * (maxWidth * .9);
    double randHeight = math.Random().nextDouble() * (maxHeight * .5);
    setState(() {
      offset = Offset(randWidth, randHeight);
      color = Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
          .withOpacity(1.0);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double maxWidth = size.width;
    double maxHeight = size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _setRandomCircleColorAndPosition(maxHeight, maxWidth);
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.cyanAccent.withOpacity(.3),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text(
                      'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$_counter',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              CustomPaint(
                painter: MyPainter(
                  offsetOfCircle: offset,
                  colorOfCircle: color,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (_counter >= 4) {
            absorbPointer = true;
            _setRandomCircleColorAndPosition(maxHeight, maxWidth);
          } else {
            _counter++;
          }

          setState(() {});
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}


class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Color colorOfCircle;
  Offset offsetOfCircle;

  MyPainter({required this.colorOfCircle, required this.offsetOfCircle});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var myCustomPaint = Paint()..color = colorOfCircle;
    canvas.drawCircle(offsetOfCircle, 20, myCustomPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```